# Traffic manager configuration is not valid because one or more domains on subscription <XXX> are not enabled for Traffic Manager

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I have two web apps deployed in Azure in two regions, East US and East US 2.

- Web-App-1.azurewebsites.net
- Web-App-2.azurewebsites.net

Both apps are on the F1 Free service plan, and each have their own service plans. My Azure Traffic Manager profile is setup with Weighted routing method.

When I try to add either web app as an Azure App Service endpoint, I'm able to select my app from the list and save the form.

I'm receiving the following error message when saving the endpoint:

`Error: Some of the provided Azure Website endpoints are not valid: Traffic manager configuration is not valid because one or more domains on subscription "XXX" are not enabled for Traffic Manager`

I have a few other weighted profiles created and configured to point to Azure Function Apps working as expected. Just not sure why I'm getting this error as I'm not familiar with a setting on the Web Apps to enable them to work with traffic manager profiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, the problem is that app service in F1 Free service plan does not support traffic manager, you need at least **standard** price tier for your app service plan. Read details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/).

[image]

Comment: That did it. Upgrading to standard tier allows me to set the endpoint as expected. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue, wherein my both app has standard app service plan.

**Error:**

> Failed to save configuration changes to Traffic Manager profile
>   'TrafficManagerName'. Error: Some of the provided Azure Website
>   endpoints are not valid: Traffic manager configuration is not valid
>   because one or more domains do not belong to subscription "xxxxxx"

**Solution:** You might have both app created is same region. In order to add it as a endpoint it should be in different region.